Modify QSPIx BACON.LEAD
I am trying to modify the QSPIx BACON.LEAD, but it doesn't change. I saw in the documentation that the BACON register has BE Write Access Mode. Does anyone know of any possibility of writing this register? I need it to set a delay before SCLK. Thank you!
Debugger_view_LEAD
When I am trying to enter any value in BACONENTRY to modify the LEAD, LPRE, or MSB for example, no change is available. I need it to set a delay before SCLK. I attached an image of how I set the values to BACONENTRY through the debugger:
Debugger_view_BACONENTRY
